# Email Verification using API and Laravel Sanctum

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I want to verify email, when user change it or create new account. I found this solution: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/verification , but probably it not prepared for Laravel Sanctum solution. The problem is with request authorization (last parameter `signature`): https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/verification#the-email-verification-handler

I have tried to write some code, but it does not work:

```
Route::get('/users/verify/{id}/{hash}', 'EmailVerificationController')
->middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'signed'])
->name('verification.verify');
```

Comment: remove `signed` middleware  it this check that route must be email verified

Comment: When i remove `signed`, laravel cannot find user.

Comment: it find user from `auth:sanctum` not `signed`

Comment: Route::get('/users/verify/{id}/{hash}', 'EmailVerificationController')->middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->name('verification.verify');

Comment: @svikramjeet then, message is Unauthenticated.